# GEE error: Image (Error) Image.reduceRegion: Provide 'geometry' parameter when aggregating over an unbounded image

Tags: google-earth-engine, image

I want to perform PCA on GEE using Sentinel 2 images of two different time period. Everything runs fine but i keep getting error

> Image (Error) Image.reduceRegion: Provide 'geometry' parameter when
> aggregating over an unbounded image

Any idea why it shows up?

```
var dist = table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_1', 'shaui'));

var image1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
.filterDate('2023-01-15', '2023-02-15')
// Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
.filterBounds(dist)
.median().clip(dist);
var s1 = {
  bands: ["B4", "B3", "B2"],
  min: 0,
  max: 6000,
  gamma:1.5
};
Map.addLayer(image1, s1, "S2 oct ");

var image2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
.filterDate('2023-02-15', '2023-03-15')
// Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 5))
.filterBounds(dist)
.median().clip(dist);
var s2 = {
  bands: ["B4", "B3", "B2"],
  min: 0,
  max: 6000,
  gamma:1.5
};
Map.addLayer(image2, s2, "S2 nov ");

var image3 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
.filterDate('2023-03-15', '2023-04-15')
// Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 5))
.filterBounds(dist)
.median().clip(dist);

var s3 = {
  bands: ["B4", "B3", "B2"],
  min: 0,
  max: 6000,
  gamma:1.5
};
Map.addLayer(image3, s3, "S2 dec ");

var stack = ee.Image.cat(image1, image3);
var sent = stack.clip(dist);
print(stack);
print(sent);


// Prepairing imagery for PCA
var Preped = function(image){
  var orig = image;
  var region = image.geometry();
  var scale = 30;
  var bandNames = ['Blue', 'Green', 'Red'];
  var meanDict = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: scale,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });
  var means = ee.Image.constant(meanDict.values(bandNames));
  var centered = image.subtract(means);
  var getNewBandNames = function(prefix) {
  var seq = ee.List.sequence(1, 6);
  return seq.map(function(b) {
    return ee.String(prefix).cat(ee.Number(b).int());
    });
  };

  // PCA function
  var getPrincipalComponents = function(centered, scale, region) {
    var arrays = centered.toArray();
    var covar = arrays.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.centeredCovariance(),
      geometry: region,
      scale: scale,
      maxPixels: 1e9
    });
var covarArray = ee.Array(covar.get('array'));

var eigens = covarArray.eigen();
var eigenValues = eigens.slice(1, 0, 1);
var eigenVectors = eigens.slice(1, 1);
var arrayImage = arrays.toArray(1);
var principalComponents = ee.Image(eigenVectors).matrixMultiply(arrayImage);
var sdImage = ee.Image(eigenValues.sqrt())
.arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('sd')]);
return principalComponents.arrayProject([0])
.arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('pc')])
.divide(sdImage);

};


  var pci = getPrincipalComponents(centered, scale, region);
  return ee.Image(image.addBands(pci));
};



print("PCA imagery: ",Preped(sent));
```

Comment: Your script doesn't include the declaration of `table`. it's related to your problem. Make sure to share it, if it's an asset.

Comment: @DanielWiell Table contains a shapefile which I imported, Link to download- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JRwGJekiYofXaCExJbKPE1entAJjdgVx/view?usp=share_link

Comment: I suspect the shape file import might have gone wrong. Please share the resulting asset.

Comment: @DanielWiell I exported the result and the resultant image is only the stacked image which has 46 bands in it and PCA has not been performed. Do I share the resultant image?

Comment: You should include the code that declares `table`, and share the backing asset: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/asset_manager#sharing-assets (the asset you got when you imported your shapefile).

Comment: @DanielWiell here is the asset link- https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-svijayteam/assets/UPshp

Comment: I don't think you actually shared the asset.

Comment: @DanielWiell here is the both code and asset link- https://code.earthengine.google.com/d08fa9cebe0df7b007fb03332fd46211

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking `clip()` with a feature instead of a geometry. Instead, use `clip(dist.geometry())`. In general, it's a [good idea](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#if_you_dont_need_to_clip_dont_use_clip) to minimize your use of `clip()`. In this case, you probably don't need to do it until you actually an image on the map. Explicitly set the `geometry` in `reduceRegion()` to your geometry, instead of extracting if from a clipped image.

You're also referring to unused band names. `Blue, Green, Red` is `B2, B3, B4` in your code.

Once you sorted that out, you'll notice problems with `reduceRegion()`. You have to increase `maxPixels` to get it running for a bigger area like yours. You will also need to run it on fewer bands. You can for instance `select(bandNames)`.

`Preped()` is also hard-coded for `6` bands. You can make that dynamic:

```
var seq = ee.List.sequence(1, centered.bandNames().size())
```

This script puts these suggestions together: https://code.earthengine.google.com/2e9cbe661d704aa7b9ee4bda6748b62f

Comment: Thanks! for all this description. It works.